# C# Index Out of Range

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am Learning c#. I am trying to get the displayName from AD. Here is the code for the following.

```
if ( resEnt.Properties["displayname"].Count > 0)
{
    nameList = new List<string>();
    name = resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
    nameList.Add(name.ToString());
    int count = nameList.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("name: " + resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString());

    comboBox1.Items.Add(name.ToString());
 }
```

The error i am getting is

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

on the line

```
 name = resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: `resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0]` its really on the line above, have you initialized this?

Comment: Which line is your error? What is `resEnt.Properties["displayname"]` ?

Comment: name = resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: What is the purpose of `nameList`?

Comment: To add multiple names i guess.

Comment: @user3200722 remove it and nothing changes

Comment: Still the error is there.

Comment: @user3200722 it's just impossible to have exception on line you pointed. You don't access any collection by index there

Comment: Seems like all you want to do is something like `var firstItem = resEnt.Properties["displayname"].FirstOrDefault(); var name = firstItem == null ? null : firstItem.ToString(); if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) == false) { comboBox1.Items.Add(name); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe resEnt.Properties["displayname"][0] is null?
Anyway, what is resEnt? is it of type DirectoryEntry? if so, you should try resEnt.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString()

Comment: resEnt is DirectorySearcher.

Comment: if resEnt is DirectorySearcher, then resEnt.Properties is a syntax error. (.Net 4, maybe I'm lagging behind?)